# How to read and assign data from picker (tried few answers from question and it still unsolved)

Tags: ios, swift, picker

So I just wanna to read which option I picked from my picker. I read a few questions and answers but I can't make it work with it. I must doing something wrong. So there is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class AddItemViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var storeNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateOfPurchaseField: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var guaranteePeriodField: UIPickerView!
    let guaranteePeriodData = ["1 Year", "2 Years", "3 Years", "4 Years", "5 Years", "6 Years"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        guaranteePeriodField.delegate = self
        guaranteePeriodField.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return guaranteePeriodData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return guaranteePeriodData[row]
    }

    @IBAction func addItemButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
        let name = itemNameField.text else {
                return // return control to the caller or do something else to indicate access denied
        }
        let store = storeNameField.text
        let dateOfPurchase = dateOfPurchaseField.date
        let guaranteePeriod = guaranteePeriodData[guaranteePeriodField.selectedRow(inComponent: print(guaranteePeriod))]
        db.collection("recipes").addDocument(data: ["name": name, "uid": uid, "store": store, "dateOfPurchase": dateOfPurchase, "guaranteePeriod": guaranteePeriod])
        displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "Success", alertMessage: "New item added successfully.", dismiss: true)
    }
```

I want to make it simple as possible and I just need to read the value before I save it to firebase.

## Edit 1

I getting error:

> Unsupported type: UIPickerView (found in field guaranteePeriod)"

This is how I trying to assign value:

```
let guaranteePeriod = guaranteePeriodField
        db.collection("recipes").addDocument(data: ["name": name, "uid": uid, "guaranteePeriod": guaranteePeriod])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read selected value with

```
var selectedItem = ""

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedItem = guaranteePeriodData[row]
    }
```

According to your Update change it like :

```
let guaranteePeriod = selectedItem
```

Comment: Yes, I heard this answer but how? I try to made some code inside but it still not working. Thats why I decided to make this question. I know, topic will be sick because it a common question but I really can't find a solution. The main question should be read and assign. Sorry I update topic.

Comment: Can you check your pickerView is correctly connected to ViewController from Assistant Editor ?

Comment: Your code looks fine.I think pickerView doesnt delegate so can you try to delete connection and add it back to viewcontroller

Comment: Ok, there is an error: Unsupported type: UIPickerView (found in field guaranteePeriod)" I updated my question # Edit 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `delegate` and the `dataSource` of the `UIPickerView` in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
guaranteePeriodField?.delegate = self
guaranteePeriodField?.dataSource = self
```

And then add the `delegate` method `didSelectRow` like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(guaranteePeriodData[row])
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how I can assign this value to guarantePeriod variable? This is my main question. Tried something like pickerView. but nothing showing up. Tried return and still nothing.

Comment: What do you mean nothing showing up? Is the array showing up in picker? Are you getting the selection printed out in console after giving this line? Provide more context as to the exact issue. Modify the question if you have to.

Comment: There is what I want to do: assign chosen value (for example: 2 Years) from guaranteePeriodField - its a picker view to variable guaranteePeriod in addItemButtonTouched function before adding document to my DB. In database I want to see 2 Years.